# I need help recovering my pre-Kerl funds

Tags: wallet, javascript, iota-recovery

I think I generated a couple addresses with a pre-Kerl version of the wallet and sent funds from an exchange to them. **I did this after the snapshots**, so the funds are not frozen by the Foundation, i.e., they're still in the addresses.

Is there any way to work through/with the Foundation to recover these funds?

Comment: I would ask them (either on Slack or directly via email). I don't think the standard reclaim process handles that case, but they can probably make an exception for you when they do the next snapshot.

Comment: Would you happen to know their support email? I found their slack at https://iotatangle.slack.com. Thank you for your reply!